# How to clear webbrowser memory in windows phone 8 programmatically in pivot control

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want to clear the memory of web browser page by page on forward and backward navigation in pivot control .I'm beginner for this platform please help me.Is it posiible?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by clearing the memory?

Comment: Yes‚I want to clear the web browser cache memory while going to next pivot index.by clearing like this i‛m thinking memory out of flow issue will reduce if any other alternatives there please help me.if you‛ve any code please post.